# Netbeans with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I installed Apache Tomcat and added it to Tools -> Servers. 
But when i create Java EE -> Enterprice Application i dont see Tomcat in list of aviable servers. I see only glassfish.

I installed netbeans with tomcat and dont see it. I installed netbeans without tomcat, added it manually, but i dont see it when i create ent.application yet.

Why I dont see tomcat?

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

press `ctrl+5`   > right click `Server`   > add server  > select tomcat add it and you will get it listed

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an Enterprise Application project that targets Tomcat.  Tomcat doesn't support all the various specs that would allow you to deploy a Java EE Enterprise Application (ear file). Tomcat supports Web Application projects (war files) which leverage a subset of the Java EE specifications like the Servlet, JSP and Expression Language specs.

The Enterprise Application wizard only displays the registered servers that will be able to attempt to deploy the EAR file that is created by building the project.

If you create a Web Application project, you will see that you can select your registered Tomcat server as the deployment target (the Server field on the Server and settings page of the New Web Application wizard).

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is helpful, but wrong. Tomcat is simply not installed, despite what the Netbeans download page says. You get only Glassfish. If you want to use Tomcat, you'll have to download and install it yourself; only then can you select it to run an application on.

Comment: [Tomcat 8](http://tomcat.apache.org) *is* bundled with NetBeans 8, "Java EE" edition, in 2015-09. But the installer may not install it by default. Click the "Customize" button in the installer app. See this Question, [No Tomcat with NetBeans 8.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33048437/642706).