# No Tomcat with NetBeans 8.1?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, installation, netbeans-8.1

I just installed [NetBeans 8.1 RC](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/81/). I cannot find any [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) [Servlet container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet). In previous versions, this was included with the `Java EE` [download bundle](http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.1/rc/) of NetBeans IDE.

Answer (score 1):

## Now Optional

As of [NetBeans 8.1 RC](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/81/), the NetBeans installer teams seems to have made the unwise choice to no longer install [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) by default. Yet they included version 8.0.26 inside the installer.

For projects using only [Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet)/[JSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) features of Java without all the other bulk of [Java Enterprise Edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition), you should use Tomcat rather than [GlassFish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish) (the other container bundled with NetBeans). For example, building [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) apps requires only Tomcat.

To access the option to install Tomcat with NetBeans, hit the `Customize` button in the installer’s panel. As seen in these screen shots.

[image: screen shot – 1 of 2]

[image: screen shot – 2 of 2]

You can, of course, install later versions of Tomcat yourself manually. Search StackOverflow.com or ServerFault.com for instructions.

For more details, see similar Question, [How to connect NetBeans 8 with Tomcat 8 in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33057955/642706).