# How to connect NetBeans 8 with Tomcat 8 in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, tomcat, netbeans, netbeans-8, tomcat8

I found other Questions and Answers dealing with getting the [NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/features/index.html) to talk to the [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) servlet container. But they seem to be out of date or involve extraneous steps. I remember the process as being less complicated on my Mac. But I cannot remember the exact steps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, getting Tomcat to talk to NetBeans is fairly simple though not obvious.

### Java EE edition of NetBeans

If downloading NetBeans, grab an edition of NetBeans IDE already bundled with Tomcat. You may need to customize the installation to get Tomcat, as described in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33048437/642706).

[image: screen shot of downloading edition of NetBeans IDE with Tomcat bundled]

But that version of Tomcat is likely to be out of date. So let‘s look at hooking up a fresh copy of Tomcat with NetBeans IDE.

### File Permissions

First be sure your copy of Tomcat can run. The permissions by default usually do not allow execution, at least in my experience on a Mac. So reset the permissions. If you are a Unix whiz, you can do so in the command-line. The rest of us use the [BatChmod app](http://lagentesoft.com/batchmod/).

[image]

I turn on all the checkboxes except `Clear xattrs`.

[image: screenshot of BatChmod app setting Unix file permissions on Tomcat folder]

Verify that Tomcat can run by executing the `startup.sh` file in Tomcat’s `bin` folder. Point your web browser to `http://localhost:8080/` to see a Tomcat page. Then run `shutdown.sh` to quit Tomcat.

Tip: You may delete all the files ending in `.bat`. Those are "batch" files used only on Microsoft Windows. Mac OS X uses the Unix files ending in `.sh` instead.

### Define a Server in NetBeans

In the `Services` pane, context-click on the `Servers` item. From the context menu, choose `Add server`.

[image]

Big NetBeans Tip: When in doubt, context-click. While the Mac convention is to provide a main menu item for every item with context-menu being a mere convenience, NetBeans depends heavily on context-menus.

In the dialog that appears, choose `Apache Tomcat or TomEE`. Type a name to be displayed in NetBeans list of "Servers". I suggest typing "Tomcat" plus the version number.

[image]

Click `Next` for the next panel of this `Add Server Instance` wizard.

[image]

#### Tomcat Location

Click the `Server Location` > `Browse` button, and choose where your Tomcat folder. I keep mine in my "home" folder.

#### Deployment Location

Turn on the `Use Private Configuration Folder` checkbox.

We need to choose a folder where we want Tomcat (specifically, Tomcat’s Catalina module) to do its work, keep its temporary files, keep its logs, and place the installed copy of your web app when you run from within NetBeans. You must create this folder. The folder’s location can be anywhere. For its bundled version of Tomcat, NetBeans uses a folder nested in `~/Library/Application Support`. But I tend to create a folder in my home folder with a nested folder for each version of Tomcat, `~/Apache-Tomcat-Netbeans/8.0.27/` for example. Unix & Java tend to get cranky about spaces in file paths, so I use hyphens rather than spaces in those folder names.

Click the `Cataline Base` > `Browse` button to display a file picker. Use the `Create New Folder` icon button in the upper right corner to create the folder hierarchy you want to use for your web app’s deployment when run from NetBeans (as discussed in previous paragraph).

[image]

#### Tomcat Manager User

Lastly in that panel, make up a user name and password to be used as a Tomcat "manager" to startup and shutdown Tomcat. Be sure to check the `Create user if it does not exist` checkbox.

The wizard panel should look something like this screen shot.

[image]

Click the `Finish` button. And voilá, you have a new Tomcat server defined within NetBeans.

[image]

The last step is to tell your project to use that server.

In your project’s `Properties` dialog, set `Build` > `Run` > `Server` (popup menu) to your newly defined server.

[image]

Comment: Just want to say thanks for this. I have literally searched the internet for an entire day trying to get this to work. This worked 100% exactly like you described. This is why I love the internet. Thanks again.

Comment: @cfsprod I’m glad to help. All three big IDEs (NetBeans, Eclipse, and IntelliJ) make you jump through a tricky series of hoops to configure an external web server like Tomcat for development/testing. Of course, three *completely* different unintuitive series of hoops, so learning one product does not help at all in learning another, except that you know to expect a frustrating hassle. I have used all three for [*Vaadin*](http://www.Vaadin.com/) web app development (don't ask why all three, long story) and all of them are a pain-in-the-rear. But, once configured successfully, it works well.