# When I try and run a JSP Project in Netbeans using Tomcat under OSX the program hangs

Tags: java, macos, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

I've been trying to set my Mac up to run a JSP project using Neatbean 8.1 with Tomcat under OSX.

I followed the directions posted on this page and I can start and stop Tomcat without any issues. ([How to connect NetBeans 8 with Tomcat 8 in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33057955/how-to-connect-netbeans-8-with-tomcat-8-in-mac-os-x/33057956#33057956))

The problem I'm having seems to be much more subtle and I can't figure out.

After I create and build my JSP project, Netbeans makes a war file

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

but when I click the Run button. Tomcat will launch but then Netbeans will stall. The only message I get from the IDE is

```
Deploying Project myTestProject ...
Waiting for Tomcat
```

Then nothing. The browser doesn't launch and nothing happens.

When I go into the my browser and type http://localhost:8080/myTestProject I get nothing.

So Netbeans is connect to Tomcat and can launch the Server Container but then nothing.

Finally after about 3 mins I get this message

```
/Users/user/Projects/myTestProject/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1045:      
Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed.
See the server log for details.

BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 minutes 1 second)
```

Any thoughts about where I should be looking?

Comment: In the "server log"? The Tomcat log file is probably called `catalina.log` or something like that.

Comment: Yes, I checked it but nothing came up

Comment: I'm confused. You say you can start and stop Tomcat, and you link to "How to **connect** NetBeans with Tomcat", all of which makes it sound like you are using a *standalone* Tomcat, not a Tomcat that comes with NetBeans. But the error says "Starting of Tomcat failed", which makes it sound like you're trying to start a Tomcat that comes with NetBeans. Which is it?

Comment: I'm using a stand alone version of Tomcat.

Comment: And Tomcat is already running when you "deploy"? --- Also, I'm wondering what's in `build-impl.xml` around line 1045, since it says "**Starting** of Tomcat failed".

Answer (score 0):

After two days of head banging I finally found my answer here.

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=262749

I'm leaving this comment for anyone who has also faced this issue. It appears to a bug in Netbeans

The fixed was simple, all I had to do was had this line of text to my server.xml -- "server="Apache-Coyote/1.1"

The Connector should look like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            connectionTimeout="20000"
            redirectPort="8443"
            server="Apache-Coyote/1.1" />
```