Tomcat CATALINA_BASE refers to C Drive however my Tomcat installation and configuration is inside E Drive
I am running a Servlet project on IntelliJ Idea Ultimate. But, while running the project, I encounter following error.
Here is my IntelliJ Application Server configuration for tomcat:

"E:\Software Development\Java Development\Servelts & JSP\apache-tomcat-9.0.85-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.85\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2024-04-16 11:30:54,189] Artifact customer-support:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "E:\Software Development\Java Development\Servelts & JSP\apache-tomcat-9.0.85-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.85"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "E:\Software Development\Java Development\Servelts & JSP\apache-tomcat-9.0.85-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.85\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21"
Using CLASSPATH:       "E:\Software Development\Java Development\Servelts & JSP\apache-tomcat-9.0.85-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.85\bin\bootstrap.jar;E:\Software Development\Java Development\Servelts & JSP\apache-tomcat-9.0.85-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.85\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Apr 16, 2024 11:30:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina parseServerXml
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf\server.xml]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\conf\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:213)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:152)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:84)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.getResource(CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.file.ConfigurationSource.getConfResource(ConfigurationSource.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.file.ConfigurationSource.getServerXml(ConfigurationSource.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.getServerXml(CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.parseServerXml(Catalina.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:709)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:746)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:477)

Apr 16, 2024 11:30:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server, server instance is not configured
Disconnected from server


I tried setting a new CATALINA_BASE variable inside environment variable but it doesn't work out. Please find me a solution, how can I update the value of CATALINA_BASE so that it detects right value.
I am expecting CATALINA_BASE value same as CATALINA_HOME variable. I don't have anything related to Tomcat inside C drive.

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54701336/22911640 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/14487462/22911640

@BondHan Just followed those question instructions but the problem lied in the application server's environment variables inside intellij idea itself so fixed it.

Fortunately, I found the answer myself in configuration section of Application Server inside IntelliJ Idea.
Just paste correct tomcat installation path here.

